# javax.persistence.RollbackException thrown when adding ManyToOne/OneToOne relationship to entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, rollback

**Scenario:**
I have a JSF 2.1 webapp running on a tomcat server, with hibernate implementing the jpa interface and mysql database.

Users of the webapp are registered as an Entity on the database, and there are a group of data called Rooms, that have their own Entity, where users have access as proprietary or as external managers. To save the concept of "external management" on the database i have a proper Entity for every management; the external management are saved as a OneToMany relathionship on the User Entity.

Here you have the Hibernate dependencies as they were added to the pom.xml of the project:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Problem:**
For some odd reason, adding the code for a foreign key to the managed room in the External Management Entity with a ManyToOne relationship, breaks up Hibernate: any update to the list of external management property on the User, when that foreign key is present, throws RollbackException - "Transaction marked as rollback only":

```
Caused by: it.katuiros.core.db.dao.DataAccessException: Data Access error while doing final commit.
at it.katuiros.core.db.dao.impl.GenericDaoImpl.closeDataAccess(GenericDaoImpl.java:222)
at it.katuiros.core.db.dao.impl.GenericDaoImpl.update(GenericDaoImpl.java:96)
at it.katuiros.appLogic.PersistenceTest.saveTestData(PersistenceTest.java:157)
at it.katuiros.beans.generics.TestBean.<init>(TestBean.java:44)
... 67 more

Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:74)
at it.katuiros.core.db.dao.impl.GenericDaoImpl.closeDataAccess(GenericDaoImpl.java:217)
... 70 more
```

*As you probably know, the sad thing about those RollbackException in Hibernate is that they are UNDEBUGGABLE!*

**CODE**

the User entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class User extends DataModelEntity {
    /**
     * Serialization ID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1154710247841840471L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    protected int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "USERNAME", unique = true)
    protected String username;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    protected String password;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "EMAIL", unique = true)
    protected String email;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    protected String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    protected String lastName;

    @Column(name = "PHONE")
    protected String telefono;

    @ManyToMany
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FAVORITE_ROOMS", referencedColumnName = "ID", updatable = true)
    protected Set<Room> favoriteRooms;

    @OneToMany
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "REGISTERED_ROOMS", referencedColumnName = "ID", updatable = true)
    protected Set<Room> registeredRooms;

    @OneToMany
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @Basic(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EXTERNAL_MANAGEMENTS", referencedColumnName = "ID", updatable = true)
    protected Set<ExternalRoomManagementPermissions> externalManagements;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "AVATAR", referencedColumnName = "ID", updatable = true)
    protected Image avatar;

    ... constructors and getters/setters ...
}
```

The External Management Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EXTERNAL_ROOM_MANAGEMENT_PERMISSIONS")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class ExternalRoomManagementPermissions extends DataModelEntity {

    /**
     * Serialization ID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7122195658297760351L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    /* CRIMINAL CODE */
    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "MANAGED_ROOM", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Room managedRoom;
    /* END OF CRIMINAL CODE */

    ... constructors and getters/setters ...
}
```

I will not post the Room Entity code, as it is not so important.

This the Data Access Object that is used to update the Entity

```
public abstract class GenericDaoImpl<T> implements GenericDao<T> {

protected EntityManager em;

private Class<T> type;

public GenericDaoImpl() {
    Type t = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;
    type = (Class) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    this.em=null;
}

protected void finalize() throws Throwable{
    this.closeDataAccess();
    super.finalize();
}

/* DATA ACCESS LOGICS */
/* BASIC CRUD OPERATIONS */ 

@Override
public void create(final T t)  throws DataAccessException  {
    try{
        this.startDataAccess();
        this.em.persist(t);
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new DataAccessException("Data Access error while persisting Object.", e);
    }finally{
        this.closeDataAccess();
    }
}

@Override
public void delete(final Object id)  throws DataAccessException {
    try{
        this.startDataAccess();
        this.em.remove(this.em.getReference(type, id));
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new DataAccessException("Data Access error while removing Object.", e);
    }finally{
        this.closeDataAccess();
    }
}

@Override
public T find(final Object id)  throws DataAccessException {
    T result = null;
    try{
        this.startDataAccess();
        result = (T) this.em.find(type, id);
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new DataAccessException("Data Access error while finding Object.", e);
    }finally{
        this.closeDataAccess();
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
public T update(final T t) throws DataAccessException {
    T result = null;
    try{
        this.startDataAccess();
        result = (T) this.em.merge(t);
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new DataAccessException("Data Access error while updating Object.", e);
    }finally{
        this.closeDataAccess();
    }
    return result;
}

/* MORE OPERATIONS */

/**
 * Method that returns the number of entries from a table that meet some
 * criteria (where clause params)
 *
 * @param params
 *            sql parameters
 * @return the number of records meeting the criteria
 */
@Override
public long countAll(final Map<String, Object> params) throws DataAccessException {
    long result = -1;

    try{
        this.startDataAccess();
        final StringBuffer queryString = new StringBuffer(
                "SELECT count(o) from ");

        queryString.append(type.getSimpleName()).append(" o ");
        queryString.append(this.getQueryClauses(params, null));

        final Query query = this.em.createQuery(queryString.toString());

        result = (Long) query.getSingleResult();
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new DataAccessException("Data Access error while counting Object.", e);
    }finally{
        this.closeDataAccess();
    }

    return result;
}

/**
 * This method returns the whole list of all T entities available on the datasource.
 * 
 * @return the whole list of all T entities.
 */
@Override
public List<T> list()  throws DataAccessException {
    List<T> resultList = null;

    try{
        this.startDataAccess();
        final StringBuffer queryString = new StringBuffer("SELECT o from ");

        queryString.append(type.getSimpleName()).append(" o ");

        final Query query = this.em.createQuery(queryString.toString());

        resultList =(List<T>) query.getResultList();
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new DataAccessException("Data Access error while retrieving list of Objects.", e);
    }finally{
        this.closeDataAccess();
    }

    return resultList;
}

/* MISCELLANEOUS UTILITY METHODS */

protected String getQueryClauses(final Map<String, Object> params,
        final Map<String, Object> orderParams) {
    final StringBuffer queryString = new StringBuffer();
    if ((params != null) && !params.isEmpty()) {
        queryString.append(" where ");
        for (final Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> it = params
                .entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            final Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = it.next();
            if (entry.getValue() instanceof Boolean) {
                queryString.append(entry.getKey()).append(" is ")
                        .append(entry.getValue()).append(" ");
            } else {
                if (entry.getValue() instanceof Number) {
                    queryString.append(entry.getKey()).append(" = ")
                            .append(entry.getValue());
                } else {
                    // string equality
                    queryString.append(entry.getKey()).append(" = '")
                            .append(entry.getValue()).append("'");
                }
            }
            if (it.hasNext()) {
                queryString.append(" and ");
            }
        }
    }
    if ((orderParams != null) && !orderParams.isEmpty()) {
        queryString.append(" order by ");
        for (final Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> it = orderParams
                .entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            final Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = it.next();
            queryString.append(entry.getKey()).append(" ");
            if (entry.getValue() != null) {
                queryString.append(entry.getValue());
            }
            if (it.hasNext()) {
                queryString.append(", ");
            }
        }
    }
    return queryString.toString();
}

protected void startDataAccess() throws DataAccessException{
    this.em = ContextEMF.createEntityManager();
    if (this.em==null) throw new DataAccessException("No Entity Manager was created! Check if ContextEMF is correctly working.");
    this.em.getTransaction().begin();
}

protected void closeDataAccess() throws DataAccessException{
    if (this.em!=null){
        try{
            if (this.em.isOpen()){
                this.em.getTransaction().commit();
                this.em.clear();
                this.em.close();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new DataAccessException("Data Access error while doing final commit.", e);
        }           
        this.em=null;
    }
}
```

}

and this is the piece of code where the user with a set of external managements is updated on the database and the exception is thrown:

```
this.externalManagement1 = new ExternalRoomManagementPermissions(this.room4);
this.dbAccessor.saveData(this.externalManagement1);
this.externallyManagedRoomsForUser1.add(this.externalManagement1);
this.user1.setRegisteredRooms(this.registeredRoomsForUser1);
this.user2.setRegisteredRooms(this.registeredRoomsForUser2);
userDao.update(this.user1);
userDao.update(this.user2);
this.user1.setExternalManagements(this.externallyManagedRoomsForUser1);

userDao.update(this.user1);  // <---- EXPLODING LINE
```

The last two lines are the critical step: if the External Management Entity has that "criminal code" about the ManyToOne relationship to the managed room, the userDao.update(...) will throw the exception; if the "criminal code" is omitted, the userDao.update(...) will NOT throw the exception.

(The room has already been previously persisted to the database before i use it in that last code segment)

**Sumptum:** I have a many-to-one relationship on ExternalRoomManagementPermissions that has a single Room as child, and a one-to-many on the User that has a collection ExternalRoomManagementPermissions children.
As i have explained the presence of the first relationship (external management to room) in the code - the "Criminal code"- makes the User unable to be updated with the collection of ExternalRoomManagementPermissions (the second relationship).

**Question:** sadly i need that ManyToOne relationship to the managed room, do you know why it breaks the persistence up?

**Post-Scriptum:** i tried to change the ManyToOne relationship to a OneToOne but it had no effect.

Comment: Where are you declaring this transaction? Your stacktrace is basically saying that you can't commit the result of the transaction either because an exception has been thrown or the transaction is declared as non-commitable. And why are you updating twice? Just put one update call at the end for user1.

Comment: Ok Dao code was added: it's the GenericDaoImpl abstract class that is extended by the UserDaoImpl class that is used inside the exloding code.
The update is done twice on purpose to show that it explodes only when i add the Set of ExternalRoomManagementPermissions.

What do you mean with service layer?

Comment: The `RollbackException` is only the symptom. There's something that caused your transaction to be rolled back. Are there additional or earlier exceptions in your log?

Comment: Sadly no, as i said the problem of those RollbackException is that they usually have no cause.
I checked the log but nothing seems to happen before that Rollback.

Comment: My usual recourse is to attach a debugger and break on the exception, then getting knee deep into the Hibernate code. With the detached entity business you have going on, I take a shot in the dark and say it's entity cache handling (see `DefaultMergeEventListener#copyCache`). Try re-fetching your saved instance of the `externalManagement1` variable.

Comment: UPDATE: i did the re-fetch, as you suggested, and the RollbackException was thrown from the re-fetch operation instead than the userdao.update(...)

Comment: Ok i think i've found the problem with intensive debug and extensive use of breakpoints... i've never when so much down in debugging in my whole life as a programmer!
The error was incredibly stupid:
"org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : it.katuiros.model.entities.ExternalRoomManagementPermissions"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OK!**

I think i've found the problem through intensive debug and extensive use of breakpoints... i've never went so much down in debugging in my whole life as a programmer! 
The causing error was incredibly stupid:

```
   "org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity: : it.katuiros.model.entities.ExternalRoomManagementPermissions"
```

Somehow *the exception was launched inside the Hibernate layer and swallowed in the same place*, that's why the RollbackException did not bear any cause in itself. I will probably post a bug signalation on Hibernate forum/groups.

By adding the default empty constructor to the ExternalRoomManagementPermissions i've managed to make the code work:

```
public ExternalRoomManagementPermissions(){
    super();
}
```

Big thanks to Tim Holloway from coderanch, Mabi and James Massey from stackoverflow for the help!

Comment: Congratulation on solving this. Dunno if your IDE supports it but I've been very lucky with "break on every exception" applied just before you run the critical part (JSF apps throw legitimate exceptions, so don't keep this on). A rollback is a 99,9% sign a method did not complete normally and an exception was thrown.

Comment: Yes i'm using eclipse.

Anyway that thing of swallowing exceptions is due to bad try/catch exception management, which is something really bad inside a world-wide standardized and famous library such as Hibernate.

Comment: Agree on the bad management part, but breaking on exceptions will let you notice them before Hibernate (mis-)handles them.